# Appending a class to the first div of a set of dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I run in to a situation where I need to append a class called *"active"* in to a set of dynamically created divs. My issue is that I am suppose to only add the class "active" to the very first of the dynamically created div set and rest not have it.

Here is my html example.

```
 <!-- Begin Carousel -->   
 <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div id="CAROUSEL_CONTENTHERE" class="carousel-inner">

        <!-- DYNAMICALLY CREATED DIVS GO HERE -->

    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is what the dynamically created DIVs look like

```
        <div class="item bgwhite"> <!-- class active should append here. -->
            <div class="carousel-img-full">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/banner2.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So essentially I would like

```
        <div class="item bgwhite active"> 
            <div class="carousel-img-full">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/banner1.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item bgwhite">
            <div class="carousel-img-full">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/banner2.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item bgwhite">
            <div class="carousel-img-full">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/banner3.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any idea how I can approach this using jquery? Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: But how do you 'create' dynamically these DIVs??? Provide relevant code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After appending your div, you can use **[.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)** to get the first div with class `item` and `bgwhite`, then add class `active` to it using **[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)**:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set.

```
$('.item.bgwhite').first().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the use of jquery, using css just add this selector with your style rules:

`.carousel-inner div:first-of-type {background:red;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#CAROUSEL_CONTENTHERE > div:first-child").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery `Append` to append any HTML you want.. and then use `:first` selector to select by the first matched element, then use `addClass` to add the active class to that element.. See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/s4swZ/

```
var dynamicDiv = '<div class="item bgwhite"><div class="carousel-img-full"><a href="#"><img src="img/banner2.jpg" alt=""></a></div></div>';

$('#CAROUSEL_CONTENTHERE').append(dynamicDiv);
$('#CAROUSEL_CONTENTHERE').append(dynamicDiv);
$('#CAROUSEL_CONTENTHERE').append(dynamicDiv);

if(!$('#CAROUSEL_CONTENTHERE DIV.item.bgwhite:first').hasClass('active'))
{
    $('#CAROUSEL_CONTENTHERE DIV.item.bgwhite:first').addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7bkbX/), for example `active` has `background:red`):

```
$('.item.bgwhite:first').addClass('active');
```

You may use `:first` to select the first item matched with classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to add class active to the dynamically created div

```
var spanElement = $("#CAROUSEL_CONTENTHERE").find(".item :first");
    $(spanElement ).addClass("active");
```

Refer the following jsfiddle link for the exact answer

http://jsfiddle.net/ShinyMetilda/J2rTh/

I have used some dummy style for .active class.You can set it as per your requirement