# Add css class to all first carousel items of all carousels on a page

Tags: javascript, carousel, bootstrap-4, dynamic-content

I want to use the carousel from Bootstrap 4 for showing dynamic content. The first item of the carousel needs the css class ".active". Actually this should be added directly in the HTML but this is a bit stricky with the my output of dynamic content. Therefore I want to add it through JavaScript and I found this topic: [Appending a class to the first div of a set of dynamically created divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813104/appending-a-class-to-the-first-div-of-a-set-of-dynamically-created-divs)

The solution is to add the following JavaScript before the closing body-tag:

```
$(".carousel-item:first").addClass('active');
```

That works so far but only if you have one carousel on your page. If you have more than, this only works for the first carousel in the code.

What I did now is to add a custom class (carousel1, carousel2, carousel3,...) to each carousel on the page and add one line for each carousel to my JavaScript file like:

```
$(".carousel-item.carousel1:first").addClass('active');
$(".carousel-item.carousel2:first").addClass('active');
$(".carousel-item.carousel3:first").addClass('active');
```

**BUT:** To be more flexible, is there a JavaScript solution as well that it works *more generic and without a custom css class per carousel*?

Thanks for any hints and tips in advance.

Bastian

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161869/jquery-how-to-select-all-the-class-elements-start-with-text

Comment: Hmm, I can reduce my JS then, but I need a unique css class anyway for each carousel I have, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the carousels on the page and from within the loop, target each carousel's first `.carousel-item`.

HTML grabbed from the BS4 docs and inserted 3 times to mimic an actual page. CSS is just to call out the 'active' items since the images are obviously not going to work here on SO.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.carousel-item').eq(0).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
/* demo only */
.carousel {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom : 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
 }
.carousel-item.active img {
  color: green;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your carousel should have differents parents, like this you can use first-of-type instead.

```
$(".carousel-item:first-of-type").addClass('active');
```

Comment: this would only work for the first carousel, the question is how to add a class to any number of carousel

Comment: @mastaH Exactly :)

Comment: @mastaH Not for the first carousel. check that : http://jsfiddle.net/fs4z9t21 . For the first carousel with the SAME parent